# What is the easiest approach to exporting a Sharepoint list in HTML format?

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010

I think the question is clear, I want the contents of Sharepoint List to exported in a HTML format. I found a way to export as XML but not HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach would be getting the SharePoint list content through JavaScript and display as HTML format. CodePlex got a great library called http://spservices.codeplex.com/.

Also, refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544538/JQuery-with-SharePoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

Why not export the list excel and then save it from excel as html, no code required